# Sync django with south

Tags: python, django, django-south

Have installed south to my old django project.

Have run.

¤ syncdb

¤ convert_to_south myappName

But the did not sync all.

Runned:

¤ Migrate myappNAme

Did not sync 100 %, still have one column that is not found.

Runned:

¤ schemamigration -auto myappName

But not synced to 100 %....

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, that your old project's models definition are consistent with database.
And you want to edit some model(s) in app named 'myappName'.
Then your algorithm will be following:

1. **Before** making any changes to you model, do:

   `python manage.py convert_to_south myappName`
2. Modify model(s) in app 'myappName'.
3. Create migrations:

   `python manage.py schemamigration myappName --auto`
4. Apply migrations:

   `python manage.py migrate myappName`

Comment: I have run the commands in that order, and it says that app and db is sync, but when I browse to the page with a new column it still say's that my new column is not in fieldlist.